# how can I query objects in Strapi using date parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, backend, strapi

example of whats im doing:

http://localhost:1337/reservas/?hora_inicio=2019-10-05T12:00:00.000Z

even copying the value, the return is empty

Comment: You've provided a link to your local environment, we won't able so access it. Provide us some real code.

Comment: I am usgin Insomnia to make query, so, dont have any code, its a simple get request

Comment: thats the object:

{
  "id": 1,
  "hora_inicio": "2019-10-05T12:00:00.000Z",
  "condomino": {
    "id": 1,
    "Nome": "Fulano 1 ",
    "created_at": "2019-10-05T11:42:37.157Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-10-05T11:42:37.157Z"
  },
  "hora_final": "2019-10-05T15:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2019-10-05T11:47:00.365Z",
  "updated_at": "2019-10-05T11:54:47.457Z"
}

Answer (score 0):

The `_inicio` filter doesn't exist.

Please refer to this filter documentation: https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/parameters.html#available-operators

Should probably be `http://localhost:1337/reservas?hora_in=2019-10-05T12:00:00.000Z`